# Kendo UI timepicker: disabled time values

Tags: javascript, php, html, kendo-ui

I'm new to using Kendo UI timepicker. How do you disable specific values from the timepicker?

PHP (fetch array for time slot)

```
 $time = $row['Time'];
```

HTML

```
<input id="timepicker" value="10:00 AM" style="width: 100%;" />
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     // create TimePicker from input HTML element
     $("#timepicker").kendoTimePicker();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly set the values:

```
$("#timepicker").kendoTimePicker({
    dates: [
        new Date(2000, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0),
        new Date(2000, 10, 10, 10, 30, 0)
    ] //the drop-down list will consist only two entries - "10:00 AM" and "10:30 AM"
});
```

or you can set min, max and interval. Depends on what you need. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/timepicker#configuration-dates

Comment: Thanks! I'll just need to set an array variable for the values and do some json_encode.